# Django forms templates: Simple question

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have a form, wich all the fields have a "help_text".. "provide your username", "your name here!", etc.

What I wanted to do, is when the form is submitted and the value wasn't provided, to show an error in that 

Example without submitting (in the template):

```
{{ userForm.username }}
<span class="helptext">{{ userForm.username.help_text }}</span>
```

If the form is submitted and the value is "empty", then it would show in error_messages the required key, in this case "This field is required", but I want to add an extra class to the span if the error type is required.

So, expample when the user submits the form with an empty value:

```
{{ userForm.username }}
<span class="helptext{% if userForm.username.errors.required %} required{% endif %}">{{ userForm.username.help_text }}</span>
```

Or something like that, hope you understand guys, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be doable using:

```
{% if field.errors %}
```

and

```
{% if field.field.required %}
```

Check [this post](http://www.skidoosh.co.uk/python-language/test-a-django-modelform-field-to-determin-if-it-is-required/) for some general infos on this.